# Condition if multiple elements have a class

Tags: javascript, class, button, conditional-statements

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="a"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="b"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="c"></button>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="a1">
    <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="b1">
    <p>text2</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="c1">
    <p>text3</p>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id ="content">
    <p>text4</p>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.hidden {
display: none}

.shows {
display:  block}
```

I want that if I press "a" shows "a1" and "content", b shows "b1" and "content"...

```
const a = document.getElementById("a")
const b = document.getElementById("b")
const c = document.getElementById("c")

const a1 = document.getElementById("a1")
const b1 = document.getElementById("b1")
const c1 = document.getElementById("c1")

const content = document.getElementById("content")

a.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
if (content.className === "hidden") {
    content.className += " shows";
}
if (a1.className === "hidden") {
    a1.className += " shows";
    } else {
    a1.className = "hidden";
}

b.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
if (content.className === "hidden") {
    content.className += " shows";
}
if (b1.className === "hidden") {
    b1.className += " shows";
    } else {
    b1.className = "hidden";
}

c.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
if (content.className === "hidden") {
    content.className += " shows";
}
if (c1.className === "hidden") {
    c1.className += " shows";
    } else {
    c1.className = "hidden";
}
```

but i want that when i press one button and all buttons are hidden "content" is hidden too, i know a way to make this is adding this code of each "click"

```
if (a1.className === "hidden" && b1.className === "hidden" && c1.className === "hidden") {
        content.classList.remove("shows");
    }
```

Nut I need another way to make it because I have to add a button each x days... may be adding an array with all buttons

```
   const d1 = [a1, b1, c1]
```

and add a for in each "click" but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You're showing the `#a` element itself, not the `#a1` one

Comment: yes @Bergi, im stupid, i edited the post. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear. Do you mean something like this?

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("button")].forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    var element = document.getElementById(event.target.id + "1")
    if (element.style.display == "block") {
      element.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      element.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("a1").style.display == "none" && document.getElementById("b1").style.display == "none" && document.getElementById("c1").style.display == "none") {
      document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none"
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" id="a">a</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" id="b">b</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" id="c">c</button>
</div>

<div id="a1" style="display:none;">
  <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div id="b1" style="display:none;">
  <p>text2</p>
</div>
<div id="c1" style="display:none;">
  <p>text3</p>
</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
  <p>text4</p>
</div>
```